# Обрезка текста по длине на чистом JavaScript без JQ

Tags: javascript, текст, форматирование

Помогите с решением вопроса, никак не получается реализовать обрезку текста по ширине родительского контейнера на определенной величине с добавлением многоточия в конце. Есть решение на CSS, но оно не кросбраузерно, также text-overflow: ellipsis также не подходит - это работает для одной строки без переносов.

Допустим есть текст, который должен обрезаться по одному символу начиная с определенной ширины блока-родителя, например после 400px. И на оборот, дополняться по одному символу назад при увеличении вплоть до 400px с исчезновением многоточия (...)

В сети есть решение с подключением JQ-плагинов, но этот вариант пе подходит, необходим нативный JS

Comment: Причём тут ширина блока? На мой взгляд нужна зависимость от количества символов, или строк, или высоты блока.

Comment: @russian-stan минимальный код для примера, пожалуйста... Что есть и что должно получится в итоге. Или ссылки на примеры.

Comment: в изначальном состоянии: Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore ad voluptatibus sed, после уменьшения родителя должно быть: Lorem ipsum dolort... И на оборот, при увеличении родительского блока текст должен возвращаться в изначальное состояние

Comment: @russian-stan Знаю, что усложняю, но хочется разобраться в вопросе. Итак, ваш текст: 1)  Единая строка без переносов в блоке для одной строки (тогда `text-overflow: ellipsis`); 2) Единая строка. Переносы обусловлены границами блока и текст упирается в нижнюю границу. "Троеточить" нужно последнюю строку ( [пример](https://getinstance.info/articles/css/truncate-multiline-text/) ) (тут только JS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал несколько вариантов. У всех есть плюсы и минусы. Все комментарии непосредственно в коде и в блоках на предпросмотре. (Для просмотра желательно развернуть на весь экран.)

```js
/*
Динамическая подрезка текста, на основе сравнения 
высот оригинального и подставного контейнера 
*/
function fCutterText() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.dynamic').forEach(function(element) {
    // Создаём фейковый элемент из блока (без текста)
    let oFakeElem = element.cloneNode(false);
    // Назначаем стили и прячем фейк
    oFakeElem.style = `
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        text-align-last: justify;
        /*visibility: hidden;
        z-index: -100;*/
        width: ` + getComputedStyle(element).width;
    // Добавляем фейк к документу
    document.body.appendChild(oFakeElem);
    // Получаем актуальную высоту основного блока
    let nHeightMain = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element).height);
    // Если у блока нет свойства "fakeText", тогда...
    if (!element.fakeText) {
      // Добавляем это свойство и запоминаем в нём исходный текст блока
      element.fakeText = element.textContent;
    }

    //console.log('textAlignLast',oFakeElem.style.textAlignLast);
    oFakeElem.innerText = element.fakeText;
    // Если высота фейка больше оригинала, тогда...
    if (parseFloat(getComputedStyle(oFakeElem).height) > nHeightMain) {
      finish:

        // Приращиваем строку большими подстроками...
        for (let i = 0; i < element.fakeText.length; i += 20) {
          // Заносим постепенно текст в фейк 
          oFakeElem.innerText = element.fakeText.substring(0, i);

          // Если высота фейка стала больше оригинала, тогда...
          if (parseFloat(getComputedStyle(oFakeElem).height) > nHeightMain) {

            // Посимвольно сокращаем строку в фейке
            for (let d = 0; d < element.fakeText.length; d++) {
              // Заносим укороченный текст в фейк 
              oFakeElem.innerText = element.fakeText.substring(0, i - d);

              // Если высоты уравнялись, тогда...
              if (parseFloat(getComputedStyle(oFakeElem).height) <= nHeightMain) {
                // Отрезаем у фейкового текста ещё 3 символа (под многоточие) и добавляем "…"
                oFakeElem.innerText = oFakeElem.textContent.slice(0, -3) + '…';
                // Выходим из всех циклов разом
                break finish;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      // Копируем текст из фейка в основной блок
      element.innerText = oFakeElem.textContent;
    }
    else {
      // Копируем текст из фейка без изменений
      element.innerText = element.fakeText;
    }
    // Удаляем фейк из документа
    document.body.removeChild(oFakeElem);
  });
}
fCutterText();

/*
Динамическое появление дополнительного элемента, 
на основе наличия полосы прокрутки
*/
function fShowMore() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.full').forEach(function(element) {
    element.querySelector('a').style.display = (element.scrollHeight > element.offsetHeight) ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
}
fShowMore();

/* Слушатели событий DOM (в качестве примера, для интерактивности блоков) */
var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  fCutterText();
});
document.querySelectorAll('.dynamic').forEach(function(target) {
  observer1.observe(target, {
    attributes: true
  });
});

var observer2 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  fShowMore();
});
document.querySelectorAll('.full').forEach(function(target) {
  observer2.observe(target, {
    attributes: true
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cutter {
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font: 16px monospace;
  margin: 15px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0em 1em 0em 4em;
  resize: horizontal;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 400px;
}

.singlerow {
  height: 1.4em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.multirow {
  height: 3.6em;
  position: relative;
}

.pseudo::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff 54%);
  bottom: 0;
  content: '• • •';
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  height: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  width: 6em;
}

.adjacent>a {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff 54%);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #aaa;
  font: .8em sans-serif;
  height: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-right: .3em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.1s;
  width: 13em;
}

.adjacent>a:hover {
  color: #a00;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .3em;
  width: 21em;
}

.dynamic,
.full {
  text-align-last: justify;
}

.full>a {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff 4%);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #000;
  font: .8em sans-serif;
  height: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-right: .3em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.3em;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.1s;
  width: 1.3em;
  display: none;
}

.detail {
  height: 3.6em;
  left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3.6em;
}

.detail>div {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-top: .3em;
  padding-right: .3em;
  text-align: right;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 1px #000;
}

.css {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0), #0d73b8 100%);
}

.html {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0), #e45125 100%);
}

.js {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0), #e4a229 100%);
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="css">CSS</div>
</div>
<div class="cutter singlerow">Одиночная строка, которая обрезается с помощью "text-overflow:ellipsis"</div>
<hr>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="css">CSS</div>
</div>
<div class="cutter multirow pseudo">А этот текст больше и не помещается в контейнер. С помощью псевдоэлемента ::before, в правом нижнем углу, даём понять, что это не весь текст. Тут, нужно добавлять контейнеру обработчик, чтобы пользователь смог перейти к полному тексту, кликнув по контейнеру.
</div>
<hr>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="css">CSS</div>
  <div class="html">HTML</div>
</div>
<div class="cutter multirow adjacent">От примера выше, отличие лишь в том, что псевдоэлемент заменён на обычный тег-ссылку "A". Этот элемент уже поддаётся более продвинутой кастомизации (анимация, стилизация, события и т.д.).<a href="#">read more…</a></div>
<hr>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="css">CSS</div>
  <div class="js">JS</div>
</div>
<div class="cutter multirow dynamic">В этом примере, задействуется реальная подрезка, т.е. вывод только того контента, который помещается в блок. Это самый правильный метод, но к сожалению, не всегда корректно работает (или я чего-то не учёл)). Ещё один минус данного подхода - малое быстродействие.
  На самом деле, кода не так уж много (большую часть занимают комментарии в коде и вспомогательные функции для наглядности).</div>
<hr>
<div class="detail">
  <div class="css">CSS</div>
  <div class="html">HTML</div>
  <div class="js">JS</div>
</div>
<div class="cutter multirow full">Ещё одна неплохая реализация, основанная на сравнении свойств <em>scrollHeight</em> и <em>offsetHeight</em>. Довольно простая и надёжная - оптимальный вариант.<a href="#">…</a></div>
<hr>
```

Если интерактивность не требуется, то функции подрезки (в примерах с JS) нужно запускать там же, где что-то меняет текст в блоке. Т.е. вставили текст - запустили подрезку.