# Как ограничить размер блока до двух строк, принимаются варианты с JS и Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется вот такая структура:

```css
.item {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span class="text">очень большой текст, который обрезается многоточием и переносится максимум на две строки</span>
</div>
```

Как корректно ограничить высоту блока двумя строчками, и если не влезает текст в эти две строки, то пусть во второй строке он обрезается и дописывается многоточие???

Comment: По ссылке выше найдешь решение

Comment: @IlyaNikulin возможно подаст идею - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/874385/265406

Comment: обычный [inline-block](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YReRMG) не вариант ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться свойством [-webkit-line-clamp](https://webformyself.com/line-clamp/)

```css
.item {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.text {
  line-height: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span class="text">очень большой текст, который обрезается многоточием и переносится максимум на две строки</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Не плохое решение, но в `FF && IE` не будет работать

Comment: @Air, согласен, решение хорошие, все получилось, но надо чтобы во всех браузерах работало...

Comment: Боюсь тут без костыля не обойтись....

Comment: @Air, например?

Comment: Глянь ответ.....

Answer (score 0):

Правда грубый костыль, но право на жизнь имеет....

```css
.item {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span> Очень большой текст,</span>
  <span class="text">который обрезается многоточием и переносится максимум на две строки</span>
</div>
```

Comment: неплохо ахаха
если, что изменил вопрос : JS и Jquery тоже принимаются...

Comment: не вспомню щас название... на `jq` есть готовое решение... когда-то встречал...

Answer (score 0):

Есть компактный вариант, но в данном виде не работает с кириллицей. Возможно кто нибудь допишет костыль и поделится.

```html
<style>
 #fos { width: 200px; height: 60px; overflow: hidden; }
 #fos p { padding: 10px; margin: 0; }
</style>

<div id="fos">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus sodales eleifend. Vestibulum</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 var p=$('#fos p');
 var divh=$('#fos').height();
 while ($(p).outerHeight()>divh) {
  $(p).text(function (index, text) {
   return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
  });
 }
</script>
```